# Source level debugging of generated code in IntelliJ

Tags: java, debugging, intellij-idea, dagger

I want to debug into code generated by [Dagger](http://square.github.io/dagger/) in IntelliJ. The source files generated by Dagger are put into `/target/generated-test-sources/test-annotations` and `/target/generated-sources/annotations`.

I've looked at the Run/Debug Configurations dialog, and didn't see anything obvious. I've also checked the Module Settings and both of **these are listed as Source Folders** so IntelliJ definitely knows they're source, but for some reason won't hit on any breakpoints I put in generated code.

Answer (score 2):

For IntelliJ 13.1.5:

If `/target/generated-sources/annotations` is marked as a generated source root, IntelliJ never triggers breakpoints. If `/target/generated-sources/annotations` isn't marked as generated source root, IntelliJ will trigger the breakpoints, but it won't jump to the associated source.

1. Unmark `/target/generated-sources/annotations` as a generated sources root
2. Set your breakpoints in the generated source
3. Run your code to trigger the breakpoint
4. Mark `/target/generated-sources/annotations` as a generated sources root

IntelliJ now behaves as expected. You'll probably need to remove `/target/generated-sources/annotations` after you're done for breakpoints to be triggered again.

I've created [an IntelliJ bug for this issue](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-130721). Please upvote it.

Answer (score 0):

All you need is the source files somewhere available to IDEA, then you should be able to debug. Make sure the folders containing the files is included in the project structure settings, then you should be able to open the files with ctrl+n and set breakpoints.

Comment: They are listed as source folders in module settings already.

Comment: Can you open them? Perhaps you need to mark the folders they are in as source root. This can be done by right-clicking the folder and selecting "Mark as". Are the breakpoints indicated with a "v" or an "x"?

Answer (score 0):

My working warkaround is:

- expand the generated artifact (jar, war, ear, ...)
- open (and decompile) the class file
- put here the breakpoint

At this point IntelliJ fires breakpoints as expected.